# Searching for a 1D torch tensor in a 2D torch tensor

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

This seems like a very simple thing, but I couldn't find a good answer for it anywhere. Say I have a 2D Pytorch tensor `x`:

```py
tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [1, 4],
        [1, 2]])
```

I want to find the indices of the row `[1,2]`, if it exists in this tensor. How do I do it?

I can of course do `x==torch.tensor([1,2])`, which outputs:

```py
tensor([[ True,  True],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True,  True]])
```

and then look for any row which has all `True` values (in this case, the 0th and 3rd). But this is impractical for large tensors.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that I've come up with is `torch.nonzero(torch.all(x==torch.tensor([1,2]), dim=1))`. This will output:

```py
tensor([[0],
        [3]])
```

which are the precise indices I'm looking for.

As a further example, `torch.nonzero(torch.all(x==torch.tensor([1,3]), dim=1))` returns `tensor([])`, since the row `[1,3]` is not present in `x`.

Comment: I feel like it's bad practice to ask a question then immediately answer it with what you've tried. This "answer" should be part of your question, showing what research you've done to solve your issue and letting others know that you're not happy with what you've come up with yourself.

Comment: What is the issue with the provided approach @SouryaDey?

Comment: @MichaelS. I am happy with the answer that I have come up with and hope that it can benefit others. That's why I used StackOverflow's Q/A format to answer my own question. I'm of course happy to hear about other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, and that is why you place it in the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. I'm happy with my approach, that's why I put it as an answer to my own question. If there are other approaches, I'm happy to hear about them in subsequent answers.